# Crazy regex: append previous CSS selector

Tags: css, regex, less, sass

A popular way of writing CSS is like so:

```
#report-page aside.sidebar {
  …
}

  #report-page aside.sidebar li {
    …
  }

    #report-page aside.sidebar li a {
      …
```

It gets tedious to write this. I want to try and automate the repeated part. (Preprocessors like LESS solve this, but I can’t use it in this existing app.)

Espresso.app can insert a dynamic text snippet:

```
    <!-- The matched suffix allows you to capture information about the text 
         preceding the insertion point. Specify a regular expression here. -->
    <matched-suffix>(\s+)(is a vegetable)?</matched-suffix>

    <!-- The transform-into element is a regex replacement expression, and can use 
    the captured strings from matched-suffix to generate a conditional snippet. -->
    <transform-into>(?2:\1is a vegetable:\1is fantastic and )</transform-into>
```

Can you help me write a regular expression that looks for the first previous curly bracket `{`, and returns whatever’s before it on that line, excluding tabs and whitespace?

Answer (score 1):

> Preprocessors like LESS solve this, but I can’t use it in this existing app.

Yes you can. Your project/framework doesn't have to support it, and you don't have to rewrite the whole css.

For example [`scss`](http://sass-lang.com/)'s syntax fully supports css's syntax, so you can just rename your `.css` file to `.scss` and it just works. After that you can start using scss syntax.

See http://sass-lang.com/

The sass/scss tool has a `--watch` switch that allows you to run it in background and automatically convert your .scss file to a .css file everytime the file is modified, while developping:

```
sass --scss --watch file.scss:file.css
```

If you prefer the `sass` syntax, `sass` comes with a `sass-convert` tool that can convert from and to `css`, `scss` and `sass` formats:

```
sass-convert --from css --to sass file.css file.sass
```

---

For you regex question, try this:

```
\s*([^\s].*?)\s*{
```

This will match the selector, without the whitespace/indentation before and after the selector.

Comment: SASS messes with Espresso’s auto-completion and syntax highlighting.  Espresso extensions to alleviate this were hastily written.

Comment: yay, that works. But how do I invert it so it finds the *last* occurrence, not the first?

Comment: /cc @arnaud576875 (it stripped out the at-reply the first time.)

Answer (score 0):

```
^[^{]+
```

This regular expression matches all text from start of line until the first opening curly bracket.  It will match the whole line on lines which do not have a curly bracket; add a literal curly bracket at the end if that is an issue.

```
^[^{]+\{
```